# Not collecting data by custom tag on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm having this kind of JS, witch collects data and pushes it on change.

```
var dataArray = [];

$(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'input', function(){
    var hid0 = $(this).data("hidden_val0");
    var hid1 = $(this).data("hidden_val1");
    var hid2 = $(this).data("hidden_val2");
    dataArray.push([hid0, hid1, hid2])
  });
});

   $('.something_here').bind('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('/do/it',
        {
            send_array: dataArray,
        },
        function (response) {
           location.reload();
        }
    );
```

The problem is that it doesn't see the target, i think? Might be that i should not use `$(this)` because he is not getting proper values at all.

This is HTML that i'm using:

```
  <input autocomplete="off" id="add_109_01000340001001001_cad" name="add_109_01000340001001001[cad]" hidden_val0="hidden_val0" type="hidden" value="01000340001001001">
  <input autocomplete="off" hidden_val1="hidden_val1" id="add_109_01000340001001001_id" name="add_109_01000340001001001[id]" type="hidden" value="112000666">
  <input autocomplete="off" autocomplete_key="add_109" hidden_val2="hidden_val2" id="add_109_01000340001001001" name="add_109_01000340001001001" onkeyup="fillFlatNumber(this)" size="3" style="height: 10px" type="text" value="1" class="ac_input">
```

Now im getting this, instead of values inside:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

If someone would be so kind and could help me out. I would be grateful.

Comment: data attributes should be prefixed with `data-`

Comment: also, `$(this)` refers to only one input box (the one you typed in)

Comment: Hey! Thank you. I Understand you. Do have any idea how to use it in correct way?

Comment: you can use `$(this).attr("hidden_val0");` instead `$(this).data("hidden_val0");`

Comment: @NiravJoshi Thank you for your answer, but i'm facing same issue :(.

Comment: `$(document).on('change'` ? is the document changing?

Comment: @RamRaider he is using deferred event

Comment: ok - I know next to nothing about jQuery but would have expected to see a binding to a form

Comment: As @Cerlin told, yes. If the value has been changed in a input field => data will be pushed to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using varying data attributes, use one (such as `data-hidden`), and ensure that you add the prefix of `data-` to them. Once you have done that, you can loop through all elements which have this data-hidden attribute by using:

```
$("[data-hidden]").each(function() { // loop all tags with `data-hidden`
  hidden_values.push($(this).data("hidden"));
});
```

Here `$("[data-hidden]")` selects all elements which have the `data-hidden` attribute, and `.each()` allows us to loop through these elements, where `$(this)`refers to the current element we're iterated on.

See example below:

```js
var dataArray = [];

$(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    var hidden_values = [];
    $("[data-hidden]").each(function() { // loop through all hidden values
      hidden_values.push($(this).data("hidden"));
    });
  
    dataArray.push(hidden_values);
    console.log(dataArray);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="off" id="add_109_01000340001001001_cad" name="add_109_01000340001001001[cad]" data-hidden="hidden_val0" type="hidden" value="01000340001001001">
<input autocomplete="off" data-hidden="hidden_val1" id="add_109_01000340001001001_id" name="add_109_01000340001001001[id]" type="hidden" value="112000666">
<input autocomplete="off" autocomplete_key="add_109" data-hidden="hidden_val2" id="add_109_01000340001001001" name="add_109_01000340001001001" size="3" style="height: 10px" type="text" value="1" class="ac_input">
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you very much! But for the last, can i use `bind` or `delegate`? Because We are using  jQuery < 1.7 that do not includes `on`. There is no way to upgrade :).

Comment: @Marshmello no worries. You can use `$('input').change()` if the `input` tags will be on the page when the page loads (see update)

Comment: `.bind()` or `.delegate()` should be fine if you need to work with event delegation

Comment: So, if i'm right, your solution looping all page values and pushing them into array? Because for me it works like this and he pushes there the whole page => http://prntscr.com/q5kyox This is strange...

Comment: Because this thing should only collect only values, that were modified and put them into an array. It should not collect whole page with data.

Comment: @Marshmello so in your example above, what data should be in the array?

Comment: Each field is unique and having 3 different values(based on input field value). They should be splitted and passed together. Why? I'm using rails as a back-end, he should read those 3 values and pass them to the procedure. I cant pass the whole page. Rails gets through all data by array witch is passed. So i need to get this 3 values in each array. And as you understand it happens when we change the input field value.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code, i will try to list it one by one

1. Data attributes should be prefixed with data. So to access like
   `$(this).data("hidden_val")` your html should be
   `data-hidden_val="hidden_val"`
2. You are adding input change event to all input fields, so when you
   edit the first input, you cannot query the second and third input's
   value as they will be empty. If you try to get the value of all
   three elements, your array will have only one correct value and two
   empty values.
3. Since you are appending the data to an array, every change in any of the inputs will add new set of duplicate values.
4. You are using inconsistent data attributes for each input like `hidden_val0`, `hidden_val1` etc. Instead just use `data-hidden_val`

So instead of reading the data on input change, read it just before sending it to server

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I'm grateful for this. I've tried your solution via `data-hidden_val="hidden_val"` but still he can not get data. So i'm getting it as `undefined`.